# How does the structure factor reflect the characteristics of particle distribution?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fourier-transform, granulated-materials

The structure factor is defined as follows:
$$S(\mathbf k)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i\sum_je^{-\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r_{ij}\sqrt{-1}}$$
It is related to the radial distribution function by Fourier transform:
$$S(\mathbf k)=1+\rho\int[g(\mathbf r)-1]e^{\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r\sqrt{-1}}d\mathbf r$$
In the paper of Zaidi ([physics of fluids, 2020](https://doi.org/10.1063/5.0011538))：

“*Generally, larger values of the structure factor for smaller wave numbers indicate faster interactions between close particle pairs or rapid making and breaking of particle clusters, and vice versa.*”

How to understand this sentence through the above two relations?

Answer (score 0):

The citation from the paper does not seem based on any theoretical or experimental evidence. The relation between structure factor and radial distribution function is basically a 3-D Fourier transform. This implies that if the radial distribution function, as acknowledged by the author of the paper,

> provides information about the overall particle microstructure in a
> stationary sense

in no way a simple spatial Fourier transform may introduce

> information related to the dynamics of the particle microstructures.

Information on dynamics requires *time correlation functions*, either in real or in reciprocal space. The time-independent correlation functions embodied in the radial distribution function or in the structure factors are not enough to say anything about dynamics, being related to the time correlation functions *at the same time*.

The presence of large values of the structure factor at small wavenumber is, in general, a signal of the presence of large clusters, but without dynamic information: a fluid close to its critical point or a two-component glass close to the spinodal decomposition may show large values of $S({\bf k})$ at small wavenumbers even if the corresponding typical times are different by many orders of magnitude.